# Break elements onto new line with flex-grow and flex-wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent div (`.tags`) that contains links and a title.

The parent div is set to `display: flex;` with `flex-wrap: wrap;`.

I would like the link elements to break onto a new line, clearing the title when the wrap effect takes place.

I have tried using `flex-grow: 1` on the title, but this makes it push the links to the right of the screen at all times, which is not what I am after.

I have attached the code I have so far, but here is a link to the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/matthewelsom/pen/yejdVd)

**What I am trying to achieve:**

**Default** - the width of the screen is large enough so nothing wraps and everything is on one line >

[image: Before Wrap]

**Wrapped** - the width of the screen is smaller, the wrap has occurred - the title now has 100% width and the links clear it >

[image]

Note that the number of links could vary.

```css
.container {
  background: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
}

.tags {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.tags span {
  margin: 1rem;
}
.tags .tag {
  margin: 0.2rem;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tags">
    <span>Tagged in:</span>
    <a class="tag" href="#">capabilities</a>
    <a class="tag" href="#">sales</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, with a change in the structure.

Wrap the tags in their own div with `flex:1`. Then *it* will expand automatically and the tags will drop to the second line when the wrap occurs.

```css
.container {
  background: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
}
.tags {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.tags span {
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
.tags .tag-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.tags .tag {
  margin: 0.2rem;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tags">
    <span>Tagged in:</span>
    <div class="tag-wrap">
      <a class="tag" href="#">capabilities</a>
      <a class="tag" href="#">sales</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/gPzNqQ)

Comment: You're going to have to do some @media max width styling

Comment: This is the correct solution - as everything is dependant on the wrap. Will clean up the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

flex grow of 1, flex shrink of 0, flex basis auto:

```
span {
    flex:1 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: That would expand the span regardless of wrapping and push the tags to the right before the wrap...wouldn't it? http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dGeBxm

Comment: In my case, Carol's code works best. I have two children in a row that I want to split evenly width wise (ie 50%/50%), then eventually they wrap down into a column automatically when theviewport is narrow enough (e.g. a narrow mobile view). All without any media queries. Flexbox is great!